# Duplicate specific rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like that:

```
timestamp               visitorid      event       itemid**
2015-05-11 05:34:49       1407572         view        122041            
2015-05-16 04:05:22       1407572         view        122041      
2015-08-30 09:03:48       130587          addtocart   65273
```

and i would like to duplicate rows with event type = addtocart

I tried that but it didn't work:

```
for i in range(len(events_df)):


        if events_df['event'][i] == 'addtocart':
            events_df.append([events_df.iloc[i]]*2, ignore_index = True)
```

append doesn't work properly

Comment: And to insert them in at the end or right after the value?

Comment: `pd.concat([df, df.loc[df['event'].eq('addtocart')]]).sort_index()` ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `boolean indexing` and `DataFrame.append`:

```
df.append(df[df.event.eq('addtocart')])

      timestamp      visitorid      event  itemid**
2015-05-11  05:34:49    1407572       view    122041
2015-05-16  04:05:22    1407572       view    122041
2015-08-30  09:03:48     130587  addtocart     65273
2015-08-30  09:03:48     130587  addtocart     65273
```